# Ignore set elements for INPUT in another div class

Tags: html, css

I dont know how to explain the problem very well, but i will try my best.

I have this css code:

```
input[type=text]{
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
}
```

This input is interfering with another input that I dont want to.

I want another input text to have the following elements:

```
#text_bar{
   width: 65%;
   height: 70%;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 10px;
   font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
   border: none;
   position: absolute;
   left: 5px;
   top:13%;
}

<div id="searchBox">
  <form action="http://dev.didieranddandelion.co.uk/shop/product-searched.php" method="post" id="search_form">
      <input name="search_input" type="text" id="text_bar" placeholder="Search Bar">
      <input type="submit" id="search_btn" value="Search">
  </form>
</div>
```

How can i get the input to ignore those elements from css and only keep the ones from text_bar?

Comment: Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

## 1) use the :not selector

```css
[type=text] { /* applies to all text inputs */
  border: 5px solid red;
}
[type=text]:not(#someID) { /* applies to all text inputs except with id someID */
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" id="someID" />
```

## 2) overwrite the property

```css
[type=text] { /* applies to all text inputs */
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
#someID { /* overrules the above CSS, while id is more specific selector */
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" id="someID" />
```